# Enabling payara-micro SSL through docker-compose

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, https, payara-micro

I'm trying to enable some security to a payara-micro instance. I'm running a standard payara-micro image through docker-compose, passing a war file (which is well deployed):

```
  version: '2.2'
  services:
    payara_micro_service:
      restart: always
      image: "payara/micro:5.2022.2-jdk11"
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
      volumes:
        - ./deployments:/opt/payara/deployments
        - ./resources:/resources
```

Now, according to the [documentation](https://docs.payara.fish/enterprise/docs/5.21.0/documentation/payara-micro/configuring/config-sys-props.html), the way to activate SSL in payara-micro is through system properties or command-line (payaramicro.sslPort or --sslport).

As far as I know you can only inject environment variable to the service. I tried anyway to set

```
environment:
  payaramicro.sslPort: 8181
```

But without success:

```
{
    "Instance Configuration": {
        "Host": "adba96fca46a",
        "Http Port(s)": "8080",
        "Https Port(s)": "",
        "Instance Name": "Pleasant-Paddlefish",
        "Instance Group": "MicroShoal",
        "Hazelcast Member UUID": "435b3b12-9c4f-4f4c-8303-abe226125e4c",
        "Deployed": [
            {
                "Name": "my-service",
                "Type": "war",
                "Context Root": "/my-service"
            }
        ]
    }
}]]
```

So, sadly, no http port set.

Any idea on how I can configure ssl through docker-compose?

Regards,

B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way:

```
environment:
  JVM_ARGS: "-Dpayaramicro.sslPort=8181"
```

Resulting in:

```
{
    "Instance Configuration": {
        "Host": "7358c95d4284",
        "Http Port(s)": "8080",
        "Https Port(s)": "8181",
        "Instance Name": "Tender-Ziege",
        "Instance Group": "MicroShoal",
        "Hazelcast Member UUID": "92118ba1-aa5f-43e0-ae04-34ab0dcf9da5",
        "Deployed": [
            {
                "Name": "my-service",
                "Type": "war",
                "Context Root": "/my-service"
            }
        ]
    }
}]]
```

After reading again the documentation more carefully, all the system properties listed can be set using environment variables (you will have to replace the dots by underscores):

```
environment:
  payaramicro_sslPort: 8181
```

Remember this is **case sensitive**.